# Как сделать любой поддомен сайта зеркалом определенной страницы?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, apache, apache2

Сейчас при открытии поддомена открывается полное зеркало текущего сайта, т.е. site.ru и some.site.ru идентичны. Задача сделать так, чтобы при открытии любого поддомена отображалась страница основного сайта site.ru/landing без редиректа на нее, т.е. на странице поддомена.

И дополнительный вопрос, как редиректнуть все возможные адреса любых поддоменов на главную страницу этих поддоменов - т.е. как сделать, чтобы some.site.ru/page1203 редиректило на some.site.ru, а там уже работали правила из п.1.

Поддоменов будет много и их названия заранее неизвестны.
.htaccess сейчас стандартный вордпрессовский.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Эту задачу решает мультисайт

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-subdomains-revisited/ и тп